LangChain ConversationChain check if tokens are of certain type
I have a LangChain ConversationChain using OpenAI and everything works well in terms of chat and conversation.
What I am trying to achieve is to detect some token types while the conversation is taking place (for example is the token an email, name, phone number, address).
The goal is to collect a "structured" conversation summary.
I have tried passing the conversation summary again to OpenAI api to return JSON for me to process but that's costing more tokens to use.
Any idea on how to achieve this?
